# Онлайн конструктор макетов для сайта

Tags: php, jquery, веб-программирование

Поставил перед собой такую задачу: Написать что-то вроде сервиса, который помогает собрать простенький сайт из готовых кусков. На выходе должны быть файлы готового сайта, которые можно лить на хостинг.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ребята, нужен ваш совет. Как такое реализовать? Какие технологии задействовать? Это мой первый проект и хочется сделать его попроще, а в последствии уже допиливать по мере изучения новых технологий и языков.

Изначально думаю использовать php jquery а предпросмотр выводить через iframe. Если есть вариант сделать это проще или грамотнее, то жду ваших советов.

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий. В чем заключается Ваш вопрос? Какой фрагмент кода вызывает затруднения? Где Ваш [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Я остановился на самом алгоритме. Не знаю каким образом через iframe показывать результат. К примеру 1) создать файл output.html в котором будет кусок кода, к примеру ХЕДЕР и этот кусок будет перезаписываться какждый раз при нажатии input'а возле ХЕДЕРа или 2) Прописать в output.html условия и при помощи if else включать отдельные блоки такие как галерея... затем output.html выводить на главной через фрейм. Или можно это как-то делать на лету?